# Adding "Desktop -> New" document program

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to change the programs that appear by right-clicking on the
desktop and then New?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add new items by creating a shellnew key for the file extension you want to add to the new menu under HKCR.

There is a step by step guide [here](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/112102-new-menu-context-file.html)